# Extra header at header row, HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I explicitly inserted, inside a table row `<tr>`, 4 columns, but I am seeing an extra that is messing up with my table design. Added a image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7exF6.jpg), must say I am fetching data from a database, first time at this. This would be the php/html markup:

```
<form action="test.php" method="GET">

<?php
    $query = "SELECT data0, data1, data2, data3 FROM table_name";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>
            <th>Info-1</th>
            <th>Info-2</th>
            <th>Info-3<th>
            <th>Info-4</th>
          </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>{$row['data0']}</td>
                <td>{$row['data1']}</td>
                <td>{$row['data2']}</td>
                <td>{$row['data3']}</td>
                </tr>";

    } ?>
```

Comment: You're missing / on the closing tag of `<th>Info-3<th>`.

Comment: This question is why it should only take 3 close voters to close an off-topic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP codes inside the PHP tags. Don't mess up with HTML tags with PHP. if you follow like this you can avoid such like mistakes

```
                <?php
                    $query = "SELECT data0, data1, data2, data3 FROM table_name";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); ?>

                    <table>
                    <tr>
                       <th>Info-1</th>
                       <th>Info-2</th>
                       <th>Info-3</th> // you are missing close tag here.
                       <th>Info-4</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['data0']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['data1']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['data2']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['data3']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Off-topic: Typo questions do not need answers, merely close the page.  Copying the whole code block to add one character is unnecessary page bloat.

Comment: so i don't necessarily need to use the echo statement, i could just use it like in your example? nice. ok.